# input data to create histogram in Quickdraw

Tags: python, animation, histogram, quickdraw

I am stuck on a question. If i have a set of data in a list (say number of students and their corresponding grade) How would I code that to create a histogram in quickdraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quickdraw](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/QuickDraw/docs/index.html) doesn't *support* graphs out of the box. Everything needs to be drawn and mapped yourself, Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/python 

import random

#create 40 random grades 
grades = [(float(int(float(20*random.random())))/2)+0.5 for i in xrange(40)]

#count the occurrence of each grade
histogram = []
for i in sorted(set(grades)): histogram.append([int(i*50),grades.count(i)])

#some grid information
gridsize = 500
griddiv = 20
topleft = 50

#graph title
print 'text', '"','Histogram of Grades','"', 220, 25

#x axis title
for i in range(1,21):
    print 'text', '"',float(i)/2,'"', (i+1)*25, 570

#y axix title
for i in range(0,11):
    print 'text', '"',i,'"', 25, 600-(i+1)*50

#grid
print 'grid', topleft, topleft, gridsize, gridsize, griddiv, griddiv

#chart rectangles 
print 'color 0 140 0'
for i in histogram:
    print 'fillrect',i[0]-25+topleft, gridsize-(50*i[1])+topleft,gridsize/griddiv,50*i[1],'b'+str(i[0])
    print 'fillrect', 'color','b'+str(i[0])
```

Save the code in `histogram.py` and run `python histogram.py | java -jar quickdraw.jar` be warned it's not very pretty! A better method would be to use the python library `matplotlib`

[image]

Comment: thanks ! I eventually came up with something similar. But your solution looks more clear than mine. @sudo_o

Comment: could you maybe help me with my latest question ?